# Is it possible to insert content from one flux to another flux based upon some filter

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I want to populate content of one flux into another based upon some condition. Here are my two flux:

```
Flux<templateVersionBo> templateVerion = templateVersionRepo.findAll();
Flux<templateBo> template = templateRepo.findAll();
```

The templateVersion contain id of a template. I want to populate template version into a template variable say template 'publishedVersion' and return templateBo flux like this :

```
    if (templateVersion.getTemplateId().equals(template.getId()) {
            templateBo.setTemplatePublishedVersion(version);
    }
return templateBo;
```

I am new to reactive programming. So not sure even if its possible or not without using block/subscribe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `id` is `Long` and `TemplateBo` has "wither" for version, you can map your templates like:

```
    // async collect id -> version map
    Mono<Map<Long, TemplateVersionBo>> templateVersionsMapMono =
            templateVerion.collectMap(TemplateVersionBo::getTemplateId);

    // get version from map by template id
    Flux<TemplateBo> templateBoFlux = templateVersionsMapMono
            .flatMapMany(templateVersionsMap -> template
                    .map(templateBo -> templateBo.withTemplatePublishedVersion(
                            templateVersionsMap.get(templateBo.getId()).getVersion())));
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally this approach worked for me :

```
Mono<TemplateBo> templateBoMono = templateVersion
            .collectMap(version -> version.getTemplateId())
            .flatMap(publishedMap ->
                template.map(templateBo -> {
                    templateBo.setPublished(publishedMap.get(templateId));
                    return templateBo;
                }));
```